# tee() function from itertools library

Tags: python, python-itertools, tee

Here is an simple example that gets min, max, and avg values from a list.
The two functions below have same result.
I want to know the difference between these two functions. 
And why use `itertools.tee()`? 
What advantage does it provide?

```py
from statistics import median
from itertools import tee

purchases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def process_purchases(purchases):
    min_, max_, avg = tee(purchases, 3)
    return min(min_), max(max_), median(avg)

def _process_purchases(purchases):
    return min(purchases), max(purchases), median(purchases)

def main():
    stats = process_purchases(purchases=purchases)
    print("Result:", stats)
    stats = _process_purchases(purchases=purchases)
    print("Result:", stats)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: tee() is used in case purchases is an iterable which can be exhausted.

Comment: Can you turn this into a running example? A couple of imports at the top, calling the functions at the bottom.

Comment: Try `_process_purchases(int(var) for var in ["1", "2", "3"])`

Comment: Pretty much what quamrana said. The first one is more versatile and can be used for both containers (like a list) and generator expressions, map objects, filter objects, zip objects etc where the second cannot.

Comment: Using `tee` in this case has not much interest though: as `min` will have to exhaust the iterator, all the values that it produced will have to be kept in memory for `max` and `median`. One could as well have created a list and run `min` and `max` on it. I just timed it, it's even a little bit faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterators can only be iterated once in python. After that they are "exhausted" and don't return more values.

You can see this in functions like `map()`, `zip()`, `filter()` and many others:

```
purchases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

double = map(lambda n: n*2, purchases)

print(list(double))
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

print(list(double))
# [] <-- can't use it twice
```

You can see the difference between your two functions if you pass them an iterator, such as the return value from `map()`. In this case `_process_purchases()` fails because `min()` exhausts the iterator and leaves no values for `max()` and `median()`.

`tee()` takes an iterator and gives you two or more, allowing you to use the iterator passed into the function more than once:

```
from itertools import tee
from statistics import median

purchases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def process_purchases(purchases):
    min_, max_, avg = tee(purchases, 3)
    return min(min_), max(max_), median(avg)


def _process_purchases(purchases):
    return min(purchases), max(purchases), median(purchases)

double = map(lambda n: n*2, purchases)
_process_purchases(double)
# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

double = map(lambda n: n*2, purchases)
process_purchases(double)
# (2, 10, 6)
```

Comment: Or just create a generator `double = (n*2 for n in purchases)` for those trying to keep `map` at bay.